# Difference between ManyToOneRel and ForeignKey?

Tags: python, database, django

In django, what's the difference between a ManyToOneRel and a ForeignKey field?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`ManyToOneRel` is not a `django.db.models.fields.Field`, it is a class that is used inside Django but not in the user code.

Answer (score 55):

Django relations model exposes (and documents) only *OneToOneField*, *ForeignKey* and *ManyToManyField*, which corresponds to the inner

- **OneToOneField** -> **OneToOneRel**
- **ForeignKey** -> **ManyToOneRel**
- **ManyToManyField** -> **ManyToManyRel**

See source of *django.db.models.fields.related* for further details.