# ManyToOne relationship with User database

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a model with a ManyToOne relationship with the user database.

Here's the code I used for the field:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class user_extended(models.Model):
    user_ID = models.ManyToOneRel(User)
```

The migration doesn't work. It returns TypeError:

TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'field_name'

How should I create a relationship with user database?

Comment: is `User` defined in this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We define ManyToOne relationships on Django with a `ForeingKey`. So you should change

```
user_ID = models.ManyToOneRel(User)
```

to

```
user_ID = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Check out Django's documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Thank you, Marcelo. It worked. Just a quick question, when do we use ManyToOneRel?

Comment: I guess we would use ManyToOneRel if we want to change some inner functionality of Django.

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300422/difference-between-manytoonerel-and-foreignkey

and the source code reference: 
https://github.com/django/django/blob/6d4e5feb79f7eabe8a0c7c4b87f25b1a7f87ca0b/django/db/models/fields/reverse_related.py

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a ManytoOne relation (many `user_extended` to one `User`), you'd do it like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class user_extended(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Note: the class name should be CamelCase, like this: UserExtended