# ManyToOneRel field for Following functionality?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I read this question thread ( [Difference between ManyToOneRel and ForeignKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300422/difference-between-manytoonerel-and-foreignkey) ) and I'm not understanding it completely. I need a many to one relationship so I can add in following functionality. Tried with a many to many and that makes two users follow each other even when one didn't want to (if one user clicks 'follow' then it acts as though the other did the same.)

Question is, will I need to use a ManyToOneRel field for the followers (who follows the logged in user) and the same for who the user is following?

Forgive me, I'm teaching myself everything and some stuff can be difficult to grasp at times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the relation *asymmetrical*, by setting the [**`symmetrical=...`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) to `False`, like:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    follows = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        symmetrical=False,
        related_name='followers'
    )
```

As the documentation says:

> When Django processes this model, it identifies that it has **a
>   `ManyToManyField` on itself**, and as a result, it doesn’t add a
>   `person_set` attribute to the Person class. Instead, the
>   `ManyToManyField` **is assumed to be symmetrical** – that is, if I am
>   your friend, then you are my friend.
>
> If you do not want symmetry in many-to-many relationships with `self`,
>   set `symmetrical` to `False`. This will force Django to add the
>   descriptor for the reverse relationship, allowing `ManyToManyField`
>   relationships to be non-symmetrical.

Comment: Do I need to set the model ( 'self' ) to my CustomUserProfile model or do I use User, where User = get_user_model() ?  Thank you for the fast response by the way,  truly appreciated.

Comment: @SilverStrings024: likely to the `CustomUserProfile`.